# How to get id from href (selenium)

Tags: java, html, selenium, href

I have a little question about selenium in java.

In my program I have a lot of href with:

```
/cms/shops/edit?id=xxx
```

```
<a href="/cms/shops/edit?id=736" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</a>
<a href="/cms/shops/edit?id=321" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</a>
<a href="/cms/shops/edit?id=123" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</a>
```

How can I get only `xxx(id)` value in Selenium (Java) and add to array for example??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code Snipppet:**

*- `ArrayList` implementation:*

```
        List<WebElement> linkList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[class^='btn btn-sm']"));
        List<Integer> idListFromLink = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(WebElement link : linkList){
            String [] temp = link.getAttribute("href").split("=");
            int id = Integer.valueOf(temp[temp.length - 1]);
            idListFromLink.add(id);
        }
```

*- `Array` implementation:*

```
            List<WebElement> linkList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[class^='btn btn-sm']"));
            int listSize = linkList.size();
            int [] idListFromLink = new int[listSize];
            for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++){
                String [] temp = linkList.get(i).getAttribute("href").split("=");   //split the href value using delimeter '='
                int id = Integer.valueOf(temp[temp.length - 1]); //get the last item
                idListFromLink[i] = id;
            }
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for answer and solutions, but when i try print id values (idListFromLink.get(0)) in console i have exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: I made a mistake. Now have a look at the updated code and let me know.

Comment: Again this same exception or when I used idListFromLink.length or idListFromLink.size() i got = 0

Comment: change the cssSelector to By.cssSelector("a[class^='btn btn-sm']")

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you shared to print only xxx(id) value you can use the following code block :

```
List<WebElement> linkList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary[href^='/cms/shops/edit?id']"));
List<Integer> idListFromLink = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(WebElement link : linkList){
    String my_href = link.getAttribute("href");
    String[] parts = my_href.split("=");
    idListFromLink.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
}
System.out.println(idListFromLink);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solutions, but i got exception:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Given css selector expression "a.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary[href^=/cms/shops/edit?id=]" is invalid: SyntaxError: 'a.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary[href^=/cms/shops/edit?id=]' is not a valid selector

Comment: missed out the quotes, try the updated answer and let me know the status